# Tagging lists of tokenized words

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I have a column in a pandas df which has been tokenized using:

```
df['token_col'] = df.col.apply(word_tokenize)
```

Now I'm trying to tag those tokenized words using:

```
df['pos_col'] = nltk.tag.pos_tag(df['token_col'])
df['wordnet_tagged_pos_col'] = [(w,get_wordnet_pos(t)) for (w, t) in (df['pos_col'])]
```

But I'm getting an error I can't quite figure out:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-99d28433d090> in <module>()
      1 #tag tokenized lists
----> 2 df['pos_col'] = nltk.tag.pos_tag(df['token_col'])
      3 df['wordnet_tagged_pos_col'] = [(w,get_wordnet_pos(t)) for (w, t) in (df['pos_col'])]

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py in pos_tag(tokens, tagset, lang)
    125     """
    126     tagger = _get_tagger(lang)
--> 127     return _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger)
    128 
    129 

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py in _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger)
     93 
     94 def _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger):
---> 95     tagged_tokens = tagger.tag(tokens)
     96     if tagset:
     97         tagged_tokens = [(token, map_tag('en-ptb', tagset, tag)) for (token, tag) in tagged_tokens]

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py in tag(self, tokens)
    150         output = []
    151 
--> 152         context = self.START + [self.normalize(w) for w in tokens] + self.END
    153         for i, word in enumerate(tokens):
    154             tag = self.tagdict.get(word)

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    150         output = []
    151 
--> 152         context = self.START + [self.normalize(w) for w in tokens] + self.END
    153         for i, word in enumerate(tokens):
    154             tag = self.tagdict.get(word)

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py in normalize(self, word)
    236         if '-' in word and word[0] != '-':
    237             return '!HYPHEN'
--> 238         elif word.isdigit() and len(word) == 4:
    239             return '!YEAR'
    240         elif word[0].isdigit():

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

If it makes a difference, my next step will be lemmatizing those tagged tokens using:

```
df['lmtzd_col'] = [(lmtzr.lemmatize(w, pos=t if t else 'n').lower(),t) for (w,t) in wordnet_tagged_pos_col]
print(len(set(wordnet_tagged_pos_col)),(len(set(df['lmtzd_col']))))
```

MY df is over 70 columns wide, so here is a small snapshot:

```
ID_number   Meeting1    Meeting2    Meeting3    Meeting4    Meeting5    col    
123456789   9/15/2015   1/8/2016    4/27/2016   NaN         NaN         [Assessment, of, Improvement, will, be, on-goi...   
987654321   9/22/2016   NaN         2/25/2017   NaN         NaN         [A, member, of, the, administrative, team, wil..   
456789123   10/1/2015   11/30/2015  NaN         NaN         NaN         [During, our, second, and, third, meetings, we...
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of col?

Comment: @Bharathshetty - added some sample data

Comment: `get_wordnet_pos` is not a builtin right?

Comment: @Bharathshetty nope - here's the function code

`def get_wordnet_pos(pos_tag):
  if pos_tag[1].startswith('J'):
  return (pos_tag[0], wordnet.ADJ)
elif pos_tag[1].startswith('V'):
  return (pos_tag[0], wordnet.VERB)
elif pos_tag[1].startswith('N'):
  return (pos_tag[0], wordnet.NOUN)
elif pos_tag[1].startswith('R'):
  return (pos_tag[0], wordnet.ADV)
else :
return (pos_tag[0], wordnet.NOUN)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply to get the parts of speech tags i.e

```
df['pos_col'] = df['token_col'].apply(nltk.tag.pos_tag)

df['pos_col']
```

```
0    [(Assessment, NNP), ( of, NNP), ( Improvement,...
1    [(A, DT), ( member, NNP), ( of, NNP), ( the, N...
2    [(During, IN), ( our, JJ), ( second, NN), ( an...
Name: pos_col, dtype: object
```

similarly its better you use `apply` function with lambda  to apply the function on every row than passing the series to the function like

```
df['wordnet_tagged_pos_col'] = df['pos_col'].apply(lambda x : [(w,get_wordnet_pos(t)) for (w, t) in x],1)
```

because you need to apply get_wordnet_pos on every cell of the column.

```
df['wordnet_tagged_pos_col']
```

```
0    [(Assessment, (N, n)), ( of, (N, n)), ( Improv...
1    [(A, (D, n)), ( member, (N, n)), ( of, (N, n))...
2    [(During, (I, n)), ( our, (J, a)), ( second, (...
Name: wordnet_tagged_pos_col, dtype: object
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I ran this code and got `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Pos_col or wordnet col?

Comment: it's the pos_col line